# Not able to extract access token google service account

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-apps

I have a consumer google account of the form 
"me@gmail.com" for which I have a service account of the form 
"Something@developer.gserviceaccount.com".  I am trying to use the private key generated for this service account to generate an access token and then may be edit or view the calendar associated with  "me@gmail.com". 
The authentication code:

```
String emailAddress = "something@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    File file = new File("path to .p12 file");
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport
            .newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(
                    Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"))
            .setServiceAccountUser("me@gmail.com")
            .build();
    String accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();
```

But the access token generated is null. The service account has edit permissions. The program is able to access the .p12 file. 
Any cue as to where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how Service Accounts work. Impersonating a user only works within a Google Apps domain. You can't use a Service Account to impersonate a gmail account.

Comment: Then where can I use the service account that is created for a consumer account? My belief was that it worked the same way as it should in an apps domain.

Comment: Your belief is incorrect. The phrase "service account that is created for a consumer account" makes no sense. Service Accounts are unrelated to consumer accounts.

Comment: Thats why I asked if what I thought was wrong then what is the use of the service account created under a consumer account. Because I can create a service account for my personal google apps id.

Comment: A Service Account is an account owned and used exclusively by a single app.

Comment: You were correct, I misunderstood the difference between the Service and Personal accounts. Service accounts are basically gateways used by applications to access or impersonate users across a G Suite Domain.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you get an access token when using a service account. If you were using OAuth2 dance and prompting the user for permissions then yes can get an access token, etc.. This is the correct way to initialize the API Calendar instance from a Google Credential object:

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
  .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```

You can then use the Calendar instance to make API calls. More information can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java